# Prove that $T$ has a unique norm preserving extension to a bounded linear functional on $\mathcal{H}$

Tags: functional-analysis, solution-verification

Let $T$ be a bounded linear functional on a subspace $\mathcal{M}$ of Hilbert space $\mathcal{H}$. Prove that $T$ has a
unique norm preserving extension to a bounded linear functional on $\mathcal{H}$, and that this extension vanishes on $\mathcal{M}^{\perp}$.

This is a question on a practice qualify exam in Analysis that I am studying for. I would like to share my attempt at the solution and hope to get some critique if my approach is correct.

My Solution:

First, $T$ has a unique continuous extension to the closure of $\mathcal{M}$, so we may assume
that $M$ is closed. By Riesz-Frechet, there is $h \in \mathcal{M}$ such that $Tx = 〈h, x〉$ and $‖h‖ = ‖T ‖.$ If we define $T ′$ on $\mathcal{H}$ by $T ′x = 〈h, x〉$ then $T ′$ is an extension of $T$ and $‖T ′‖ = ‖T ‖ = ‖h‖.$  Clearly, $T ′$ vanishes on $\mathcal{M}^⊥$.

Uniqueness: suppose $F$ is another norm preserving extension of $T$ . Then
there is $g \in \mathcal{H}$ such that $F x = 〈g, x〉,$ and $‖F ‖ = ‖g‖ = ‖T ‖.$ Since $F$ and $T ′ $are equal on $\mathcal{M}$, we have that for all $x \in \mathcal{M}, 〈h, x〉 = 〈g, x〉$ so $g − h \in \mathcal{M}^⊥.$ Thus, $g − h ⊥ h$ which implies that
$g = (g − h) + h$ and $‖g‖^2 = ‖g − h‖^2 + ‖h‖^2.$ It follows that$ ‖T ‖^2 = ‖g − h‖^2 + ‖T ‖^2 $ whence $g = h.$

Comment: Yes, that is correct.

Comment: Thank you for the affirmation!